# Where is TinyMCE 4 handling click event on list menu buttons to show/hide them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I need to customize tinymce's behavior to show/hide the menus like styleselect,charmap,fontsize, etc.

It's happening something weird with those list menus. They always keep active even if I click another sibling menu. Where the default behavior should be close the old menu to open the new one.
It has be something related to my project.

I was trying to do a self.hideAll(), which works, but affects the submenus of list menus as well by resetting their position to 0,0 of container.

Does anyone know where are these click events being handled? I can't find them. 
If I get to know that i just simply add hideAll there in the click event and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it out after hours of debugging. If someone is under the same situation because is doing "tricky" things with tinyMCE like me, the bindClickHandler in tinymce was being done in document and I needed to listen at parent.document as well.